# Incremental variable use in bash script when concatenating files

Tags: bash, concatenation

I have 100 .pdb files that I need to concatenate to another single .pdb file.  I am using a bash script and the cat command but cant write an incremental variable properly!!  There is one T0950-A.pdb file and 100 T0950-B_1.pdb files incrementally numbered up to 100 using the last number in the filename.  Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#concatenate pdb A file to 100 pdb B files

COUNTER=0
while [ $COUNTER -lt 101 ]; do
    ./cat T0950-A.pdb T0950-B_[$COUNTER].pdb > Frodock-T0950_[$COUNTER].pdb
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done
```

Thank you very much for any help in advance.

Comment: Are there only 100 PDB B files or do you just want to process the first 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for pdbb in T0950-B_*.pdb; do
    cat T0950-A.pdb "$pdbb" >"Frodock-T0950_${pdbb#*_}"
done
```

The `${pdbb#*_}` parameter substitution would turn the string `T0950-B_55.pdb` into `55.pdb` (removes everything up to and including the first `_` character).

This relies on the existing PDB B files and does not try to iterate over integers.

If you wanted to *only* loop over the first 100 PDB B files, then you could use

```
for pdbb in T0950-B_{1..100}.pdb; do
    cat T0950-A.pdb "$pdbb" >"Frodock-T0950_${pdbb#*_}"
done
```

or

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 100; ++i )); do
    pdbb="T0950-B_$i.pdb"
    cat T0950-A.pdb "$pdbb" >"Frodock-T0950_${pdbb#*_}"
done
```

but these two variations does not guarantee that the files iterated over actually exists.

---

Responding to comments (there are files with names like `H0957-B.1.pdb` too).

Yes, these would not be picked up by the above code.  Instead, you would do something like

```
for pdbb in H0957-B.*.pdb; do
    cat H0957-A.pdb "$pdbb" >"Somename-H0957_${pdbb#*.}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works perfectly and is a more elegant solution that my attempt :D

Comment: okay I have some other pdbs where the filename is H0957-B.1.pdb and the . before the number in the filename makes your code stop working, and I don;t understand why!